# Proving $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(X)]=X$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.

Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{F}-$measurable random variable.

Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(X)]=X$ almost surely, where $\sigma(X)$ is a sigma algebra generated by $X$.

Here is attempt.

Let $\mathcal{G}:=\sigma(X)$.

We first to show that for all $A\in \mathcal{G}$,
\begin{equation}
\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}](\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_A X(\omega)dP(\omega).
\end{equation}
By definition of $\sigma(X)$, for any $A\in \mathcal{G}$ there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $X^{-1}(B)=A$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel set. Then
\begin{align}
\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}](\omega)dP(\omega) &=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]\cdot P(A) \quad
 (\because \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] \text{ is } \sigma(X)-\text{measurable, hence constant over }X^{-1}(B)=A)\\
& = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]\cdot \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}] \quad (\because P(A)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}])\\
& = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}\cdot \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]]  \quad (\text{again, } \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] \text{ is constant over }A)\\
& = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\cdot \mathbb{1}_{A}|\mathcal{G}]] \quad (\because \mathbb{1}_{A} \text{ is } \mathcal{G}-\text{measurable} )\\
& = \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \mathbb{1}_A] \quad (\text{by Iterated Law of Expectation} )\\
& = \int_A X(\omega)dP(\omega).
\end{align}
Next step is to show that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]=X$ almost surely. But I am stuck at this step.

How can I come to a conclusion? Also, could anybody verify that the steps so far are indeed true?

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**  $\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,\mathcal G] = Y$ means:
(a) $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and
(b) for all $A \in \mathcal G$, $\mathbb{E}[X\;\mathbf1_A]=\mathbb{E}[Y\;\mathbf1_A]$.

Check that this is true when $Y=X$ and $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$.

Comment: So is it the case that there is nothing to prove, and the statement above is just straightforward from the definition?

Comment: This works when $X \in L^1$, but OP's question is more general.

Comment: OK, we need a definition of $\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,\mathcal G] = Y$ in case $X \not\in L^1$.  I guess if $X \in L^2$, then this is an orthogonal projection.